# JQuery :: Capture hover event and change CSS on child div

Tags: jquery, jquery-hover

I know I'm missing a small piece of this ... but for markup like this:

```
<a class="menusegment"><div>Link Text & Link Description</div></a>
```

I have the following jquery

```
$('a.menusegment').hover(function () {
    // insert code here
});
```

What I want to do is change the top border color of the div contained in 'a.menusegment'

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Is the fact that the `div` is unclosed intentional?

Comment: what is the problem you are facing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(function(){
    $('a.menusegment').hover(function () {
        var thisNode = $(this);
        thisNode.children('div').css('border-top', '1px solid #f60');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('a.menusegment div').hover(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();

    // change color here
},
function(){
//code to execute on mouseleave
}
);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3Bh5J/

Answer (score 2):

If i understand your question... You dont need any kind of js

In CSS:

```
a.menusegment:hover div{
border-top:solid red 1px;
}
```